# Adding to string array

Tags: java

I have a java code that looks like this:

```
x = Math.random() * emotion.length;
Feeling = (int)x;
System.out.println(emotion[Feeling] + " How are you?");
NewEmotion1 = NewEmotion.nextLine();
emotion.add(NewEmotion1);
```

Eclipse gives me and error that says "Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type String[]". emotion is and Array. I am trying to add NewEmotion1 from the scanner to emotion.
I initiated emotion like this:

```
String[] emotion = new String[]{"Ecstatic", "Meh.", "Bad.", "Good."};
```

I only want it to show one random emotion at a time.

I show the length of the array with this code:

```
String[] emotion = new String[]{"Ecstatic.", "Meh.", "Bad.", "Good."};
```

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `Emotion` (which should be called `emotion`, by the way) an array? Then you can't `add` to it. What are you trying to do here, exactly? What is the context? Do you need to read an arbitrary number of strings?

Comment: Can you share how did you initiated the Emotion variable?

Comment: Arrays in Java have fixed length. You can only assign elements to arrays at indexes in range `0` till `length-1` via `arrayName[indexValue]=valueYouWantToPlace;`. There is no `add(valueYouWantToPlace)` in arrays. There is in `List` (like `ArrayList`) which you may be after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initiating a **dynamic** list should be as the follow:

```
List<String> emotion = new ArrayList();
```

By the given error, I can assume you initiated the array in this way:

```
String[] emotion = new String[X]
```

where `X` represents the capacity of the array, which would be fixed size.
By initiation an array in your case, using `emotion[i] = YOUR_STRING`, where `0 <= i < X` will solve your problem.

as Federico klez Culloca suggest, using lowcase letter for variables is more intuitive.

**UPDATE**

Since each time you want to add a new emotion to the list, this example will help you understand the flow:

```
    Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> emotions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Ecstatic", "Meh.", "Bad.", "Good.")); //initiating dynamic list
    Random rand = new Random(); //for random number
    String randomEmotion = emotions.get(rand.nextInt(emotions.size())); //gets a random emotion,
    System.out.println(randomEmotion + " How are you?");
    String newEmotion = io.nextLine(); //gets an input from the user.
    emotions.add(newEmotion);
```

Comment: what do you mean by showing one at a time, if you already knows the values on your list, what are you trying to add?

Comment: I want it so if this is in a loop every time it prints something from emotion array, then you write how you are, and then your response is then recorded in emotions in can print out.

Comment: so the user inputs gets inserted into the array?

Comment: I have a piece of code that tells me the length of emotion array, and when I use i = emotion.length - 1, the length of the array is 4 no matter how many time it goes through the loop.

Comment: Yes, the user input goes in the array so as long as it's open it can use that feeling.

Comment: so you need to share with us the piece of code that tells you the length of emotion array..